# How to make polling script using javasctipt and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, progress, polling

I have a script that runs a long conversion php script and a progress polling script. After looking at several posts about this subject i found that it should be possible to use async ajax calls combined with timeout from javascript to create a construction that would poll the progress regularly and update my page with a percentile number. See code below

```
function startExcelConversion(excelname){

var poll = function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({ 
         url: "../include/ajax/ajax.php?action=poll_progress", 
         success: function(data){
             //Update the progress bar
            // show progress
            console.log('progresser: '+data);
            $("#progress").val(data);
             //Setup the next poll recursively
             poll();
         }, 
         complete: function( jqXHR, textStatus ){
             //Update the progress bar
            // show progress
            console.log(textStatus);
         },
         dataType: "json"
     });
  }, 3000);
};    

poll();

//show loading image
console.log('starting conversion');
$('#progress').val("Excel openen...");
$('#main').prepend('<img id="loading" src="../include/image/load.gif">');
$("#loading").show();

$.ajax({         
url: '../import/import_main.php?clean&action=importexcel&excelname='+excelname,         
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#main").html(data)
    $('#loading').hide();        
}     
});



return false;
```

}

the first block launches the script that runs a while (excel reading and conversion).This script updates a database table every 10 rows to set the progress. the second block (from start polling onwards0 should launch a php script that reads this progress db field and echo it so i can update my input field with the percentile. However the polling script is not called during the runtime of the first php script (import_main.php). I tried $.post and $.get calls (which should as $.ajax be asynchronous by default). Also tried setInterval but that did not work and was not recommended due to timing problems. Am i missing something obvious here or is it a setting in php i am missing?

thnx in advance

Comment: poll() is not going to be defined in above code

Comment: yea, but in the success callback, you try to call it using poll();

Comment: no reason to use a closure like that here anyway, no benefit.

Comment: Ahh, you're right, the succes scope does not contain that definition. Smart

Comment: If he would use it as a normal function instead of an IIFE his code would work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out the problem was threefold:

The first problem was indeed the use of an IIFE function that was not defined at runtime. So using inline function such as z416175 described was certainly valid

The second problem was that when a session is active in PHP it will block other (ajax) calls to prevent session overwriting. So using session_write_close() before entering the long running script worked to allow asynchronous ajax calls for progress updating. See this post (thnx to z416175) [One ajax call block other ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076970/one-ajax-call-block-other-ajax-call)

The third problem was that when you use xdebug the second problem remains because xdebug keeps a session open preventing the asynchronous ajax progress update call. So be aware when testing that xdebug causes problems with this

Thanks for all input. I have credited z416175's post for various usefull info in his answer and comments

Answer (score 1):

I would try to define poll at the top of the script, like:

```
var poll = function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({ 
         url: "../include/ajax/ajax.php?action=poll_progress", 
         success: function(data){
             //Update the progress bar
            // show progress
            console.log('progresser: '+data);
            $("#progress").val(data);
             //Setup the next poll recursively
             poll();
         }, 
         dataType: "json"
     });
  }, 3000);
});
```

and then call it, like, `poll()`, after the ajax call.  See if that helps.  Right now, you have an anonymous function after the ajax call, but it tries to call itself with poll(); in the success callback, which isn't going to be defined.

Comment: His problem is that he is using an IIFE. It doesn't matter that he used the function after the declaration. A normal object(function) will be available because it is defined at compiletime. An IIFE is defined at runtime. Check out my http://jsfiddle.net/pdymbedg/

Comment: i did not realize the function would not be defined. However after adjusting the script my polling function still is not called/executed at all. I now define the poll as a function variable as stated in the code. Then make the first ajax call to the conversion script and then call poll(); to no avail. Also tried to call it before the first ajax call but nothing. I even added a complete callback function to the poll in case there was an error but that too is never reached. I will update the code in my question to reflect

Comment: hmm...code seems fine otherwise, at least on javascript side, and its very weird that its not hitting the success or error callbacks.  If you're on Chrome, you should check out the Network tab in debugger (make sure record is activated, top left corner), and see if the ajax is ever even made, maybe get some more info.

Comment: my guess is problem is php side otherwise, else you should get a success or error callback.

Comment: that could be, but the weird thing is that i can set a breakpoint in main_import.php script which it will hit and stop (using netbeans with xdebug) but the ajax.php script it will not stop. I tested the ajax.php script and there are no errors (just a queury and a print of the percentile). The import script uses a lot of memory and is time consuming (using phpexcel to read excel file) but the whole point is that i could update the progress asynchronously

Comment: also i tried to remove the whole first ajax call so only the poll script would be called and that DID work: every 3 seconds my progress was updated. But when the time consuming script is running nothing...

Comment: The time consuming script will not 'consume time' within Javascript on the client side, JS is just going to make the request and wait for the callback, all the time consumption is on the server.  The fact that the ajax.php script works if you don't call the main_import.php script, and doesn't return anything otherwise, success or failure, indicates to me that the problem has something to do on PHP side.

Comment: Both PHP scripts are accessing the database, right?  Crazy thought, but maybe one script is blocking the other from connecting.

Comment: i understand that the script is not consuming client side time, hence the php ajax call. It looks like it is indeed something on the server side script. Could the long running script be consuming all the server resources so that the other ajax call is not getting processing time? All i can say further is that i use mysqli to execute (prepared) queries and i tried to manually close the connection each time this happens but that did not do the trick. Also i do not think that this is the problem because my polling script does not stop at the breakpoint which is before any db connection is made

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm unable to make any determinations without seeing what's going on server side.  Check this answer out, first thing I found on search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076970/one-ajax-call-block-other-ajax-call