# PHP usleep() causes a hold on all of my php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm setting up a comet longpolling message system.
Using jQuery and PHP. jQuery is what I use for ajax.
The problem is that, in the php file that  is ajaxed to, that waits for data in a while loop before returning, is causing all of my other ajax requests the be pending until it returns. In the loop I call usleep().

It seems as though usleep is freezing all of my other PHP, even though they are seperate files. Kinda weird. How can I solve this issue? Heres comet php longpolling file :

```
<?php

session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['userID'])) {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "not-loggedIn"));
    die();
}

if (empty($_GET['friendID'])) {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "friendID-invalid"));
    die();
}

include("../../tools.php");

$html = getNewLiveChatMessages($_GET['friendID'], $_GET['messageID']);

if (!$html) {
    $timeout = 2;
    while ($timeout > 0) {
        $html = getNewLiveChatMessages($_GET['friendID'], $_GET['messageID']);

        if ($html) {
            break;
        }

        $timeout--;
        /* Wait 10 seconds */
        usleep(10000000); /* In microseconds */
    }
}

echo json_encode(array("status" => "success", "html" => $html));

?>
```

Comment: @CollinD yes you're right. i'll delete my comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076970/one-ajax-call-block-other-ajax-call